# Web Design/Development

Tags: php, html, css

I have been learning web design/development for a while. I have basic knowledge of CSS(3),HTML,PHP,MySql(i). I also started exploring Drupal.

Now, I tried to use DRUPAL but it's not perfect. (Memory Expensive/Less Freedom). I am also not expert enough to tear down everything from Drupal and use things.

I then started to notepad and tried to create with every single HTML tag. It's not as exciting when you are not perfect.

I could combine Dreamweaver GUI and my own coding or free codes from external sources. I do not have access to DREAMWEAVER which is a great tool.

I have seen Expression Web but did not have time to explore.

Given my middle level of knowledge, and constraints, which path is best for me? (Continue with notepad(or basic html editors)/Try Expression Web/try to be happy DRUPAL/other solutions).

I want to make it dynamic with features like user registration/search feature/APIs/. I will include a lot of external codes. (This was one of the places I had difficult implementing in DRUPAL).

Comment: This is the wrong type of question for this site.

Comment: is there suitable SE site for this?

Comment: Real web designers do not use DreamWeaver. Personally I use Notepad++

Comment: This is question is overly-broad and will likely be closed. SyackOverflow is more geared towards "how do I do X", rather than system-wide questions.

Comment: @Kolink - You mean they didn't build SO in Frontpage?!

Comment: You can try http://programmers.stackexchange.com, but be careful to read their help documentation and on-topic list first. Ultimately, the decision about "best path for you" is going to be made by you, not by others. Try one; if it doesn't work out, you can always try something else.

Comment: @Revent and George Cummings, wanted to delete but don't have option since there is an answer. Anyone else, don't move to any other site but close if you wish. Thanks everyone! It's encouraging to know that real developers use notepad++. and I just wanted to know what real developers would do.

Comment: On [the php tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) There is a laundry list of good free IDE's for PHP development

Comment: @user2178841 Be sure to take the Notepad++ comment with a grain of salt. It's a bit like saying "real men build their own houses" or "real men don't use air conditioning." It's not always the best or most efficient solution, and it may not be very comfortable. There's nothing wrong with coding without an IDE, but you may find that you are more productive with one.

Comment: `Sublime Text 2`, or if you're feeling `hardcore` `VIM` or `Emacs` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the kind of things you want to do, you really need to bear down and learn how to do it in a text editor. While you don't need a mastery of PHP/JS/CSS (because of libraries and things like that), there really is **no** substitute for simply knowing how the back end works, **especially** if you're looking to create unique and dynamic webpages.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free tool I used to use a while back called [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). It had some intellisense features for PHP/HTML.

Stay away from WYSIWYG editors at this stage - like the JNatalzia said, you should know how the back end works. There's nothing worse than trying to work with a developer who doesn't know basic HTML syntax and can't make a change that the WYSIWYG editor doesn't support (and believe me, they ALL have things you can't do without getting your hands dirty in code).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be a proficient web developer or designer, don't use any wysiwyg editor for HTML and CSS.

My suggestion to you is to work on the languages themselves, without any plugin at all, and ensure that you understand and know the basics of each of them. Use a simple text editor (NotePad++) until you feel comfortable with them, then you should move to frameworks and other tools.

Comment: +1 Just wanted you to go over 1000.

Comment: Hahaha thanks, that 999 was tough :)